# how to save database versioning as a sql_last_version variable in logstash

Tags: sql, postgresql, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

What I'm trying to do is to save the greatest version of rows in the `sql_last_value` parameter as shown below in my `log.conf` file after each time it executes.

This is my `log.conf` for logstash:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/test"
        jdbc_driver_library => "/home/postgresql-42.2.18.jar"
        # last_run_metadata_path => "/usr/share/logstash/.logstash_jdbc_last_run"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        jdbc_user => "postgres"
        jdbc_password => "postgres"
        parameters => { "sql_last_version" => 400 }
        schedule => "*/5 * * * * *"
        statement => "SELECT * FROM test where xmin::text::int >= :sql_last_version ORDER BY xmin::text::int "
    }
}

filter{
    
}

output {   
    stdout {
        codec => json_lines
    }
}
```

for instance, this is my table:

```
test=# select *,xmin from test where xmin::text::int >= 400 order by xmin::text::int;
 id |   name   | xmin 
----+----------+------
  1 | Robert   |  300
  2 | Jessica  |  400
  3 | Jennifer |  500
  4 | Jack     |  600
(4 rows)
```

I'm expecting to store 600 as the `last_version` parameter.

I'm sure if mistaken or not, I've got no ideas here, please help. I'm a total newbie to logstash.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The parameter is called `sql_last_value`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_configuring_multiple_sql_statements) and here is how you can use it:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/test"
        jdbc_driver_library => "/home/postgresql-42.2.18.jar"
        # last_run_metadata_path => "/usr/share/logstash/.logstash_jdbc_last_run"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        jdbc_user => "postgres"
        jdbc_password => "postgres"
        schedule => "*/5 * * * * *"
        use_column_value => true
        tracking_column => "xmin"
        statement => "SELECT * FROM test where xmin::text::int >= :sql_last_value ORDER BY xmin::text::int "
    }
}
```

Here are the modification I made:

- You don't need the `parameters` setting
- You're missing the `use_column_value` setting
- You're missing the `tracking_column` setting
- The SQL query needs to reference `sql_last_value` not `sql_last_version`

After the first run, `600` will be stored in `sql_last_value` and used in the next call to only retrieve records whose `xmin` value is >= 600 (which means the last record will be fetched again)

Comment: Thanks for answering, xmin is a system column in PSQL, and jdbc cannot tracking it, but if I use id column it is ok, what is your opinion ?

Comment: Is there a way to alias that column in the query and use the alias name instead?

Comment: It's working now! cheers buddy, so much thanks, you're Elastic GOD :)